# Can you banish maiden with the eyes of blue even if it is face up?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I play Yugioh at school and the main person I play against has a Blue-Eyes deck. He uses [Maiden with Eyes of Blue](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Maiden_with_Eyes_of_Blue) and says I can't destroy it. But I read somewhere that you can banish it.

Is this correct?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site! Unfortunately, there isn't quite enough context in your question to determine exactly how someone should answer it. Yu-Gi-Oh has virtually limitless possible combinations, so depending on the exact scenario, the correct answer will vary. Please provide more information - like the cards/actions involved with this specific interaction, and what you're trying to do that your friend is suggesting you aren't allowed to.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica hey there. Sorry but the question is highly answerable and makes sense. The post already asks a genuine question and has sufficient information for someone who knows abut the game to answer. This is a clear case where we can help OP learn their ways on this card game...

Comment: @DarkCygnus I disagree, I think clarification as to what is occurring in the game is very important here. We need to know what OP is trying to do in this scenario, so we can know whether or not it should actually be able to occur. E.g., suppose OP is wondering something like if his attack with [D.D. Warrior Lady](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/D.D._Warrior_Lady) will result in Maiden being banished here... clearly it would not, but we don't have the context to know.

Comment: The point is that by analyzing Maiden's effect all cases are covered regarding OP's question. Which is if Maiden can be destroyed or banished in the cases mentioned.

Comment: @DarkCygnus "If Maiden can be destroyed or banished in the cases mentioned" - No cases were mentioned, that's what I'm saying. Evidently there was a scenario that lead OP to believe his friend, and find something that said "but it can be banished." He also adds an additional "even if it is face up" to the question, which to me is a clear indication that there must be some other cards involved here.

Answer (score 1):

Let's read [Maiden with Eyes of Blue](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Maiden_with_Eyes_of_Blue)'s effect, emphasis mine:

> When a card or effect is activated that targets this card (Quick Effect): You can Special Summon 1 "Blue-Eyes White Dragon" from your hand, Deck, or GY. When this card is targeted for an attack: You can **negate the attack**, and if you do, change the battle position of this card, then you can Special Summon 1 "Blue-Eyes White Dragon" from your hand, Deck, or GY. **You can only use 1 "Maiden with eyes of Blue" effect per turn, and only once that turn**.

We can see that *nowhere on it's card text reads that it cannot be destroyed.* Thus, otherwise there is another card your opponent has, the Maiden is not indestructible by herself.

When you target her with any effect, she special summon a Blue-eyes, but she does not negate that effect.

When you attack her, she negates *the first* attack, and special summons a Blue-eyes. However, if you attack her again she will take the hit.

In short, you can target and destroy the Maiden by various means, as nowhere on it's text is indicated otherwise. Just, be ready to handle the Blue-Eyes White Dragon that comes with you doing that.